# Domain name already registered but there is no whois record

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I searched for a domain name it found already registered but when I searched it in who.is no result found

```
Whois Error: No Match for "xxxxxxxxxxx.COM"

Information Updated: 2017-05-09 04:01:35
```

Is it possible to buy this domain name?

Comment: What "tool" told you it was already registered?

Comment: Check the domain using domaintools.com. That's it is a fairly accurate and authoritative site.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if the domain is registered there should be some record even if it is protected.

I would say, try different whois record checker.

Answer (score 1):

Use the relevant registry whois server (either CLI or website). If this is really a `.COM` see https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/com.html for which whois server to query and website to visit.

If you use any other tool than the registry provided one, you expose yourself to partial/delayed/wrong results and/or surveillance and logging of your queries.